# Run as java application brings up select java application screen, no further instruction

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

Asking because I'm following Guru99's time sensitive selenium course and the code that I have downloaded as part of my project will not run as a java application.
It is supposed to be ran with only this code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class TestScript01 {  

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {     


    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    String baseUrl = "http://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/";

    // launch Firefox and direct it to the Base URL
    driver.get(baseUrl);


    // Enter username
    driver.findElement(By.name("uid")).sendKeys("xxxx");

    // Enter Password
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("xx");

    // Click Login
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();


    }


}
```

However, I have added: `import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;` and `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                   "C://selenium/chromedriver.exe");`
I've also not included my real username and password in code above
I have downloaded Chrome driver to the selenium folder in my C drive

I was trying to run from firefox initially but was stuck on `Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms` errors, which I downgraded my firefox for as that worked for many on this site, but it was still giving me the same error so I switched to Chrome, which selenium seems to prefer. I'm using the latest version of Chrome and Firefox 47.0

I'm using selenium 3.6.0 and jdk 1.8.0_111

When trying to run as an application, according to the instructions, I seem to be in a loop where I keep getting this screen:

[image: See the image below]

I have never had to select an option in order to run a selenium script before, not sure why I'm getting it now or what I'm supposed to select if any.

I have googled but it seems that most instructions for running selenium tests do not include this pop-up. I thought that instantiating a new `WebDriver` object and selecting the right imports were enough, what am I missing?

Comment: what is ur error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havn't mentioned the **`Selenium`**, **`ChromeDriver`**, **`Chrome Browser`**  and **`JDK`** versions. Assuming you are using the latest version of **`Selenium`**, **`ChromeDriver`**, **`Chrome Browser`**  and **`JDK`**, I would suggest a few steps as follows:

1. Instead of `import org.openqa.selenium.*;` always use `import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;` and the required ones.
2. While working with **`Selenium 3.x (Java)`** it is mandatory to mention the following line :

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
   ```

   In this line you have to either use single front slashes `/` or you have to use escaped back slashes `\\`
3. The screen with **`Select Java Application`** indicates there are multiple overlapping `imports` in your project or `methods` from overlapping `jars`. We need to keep only the used `imports` in your script & used `jars` in your project and remove the other `imports`/`jars` from your `script`/`project` to keep it simple.
4. From your `IDE` take a `Project -> Clean` for all the projects and keep `Build Automatically` selected.
5. Error `Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms` can arise for many reasons. The best remedy is to `uninstall` the `Browser` with **`Revo Uninstaller`**, Run **`CCleaner`** to wipe out all the rotten OS stuffs and take a system reboot and trigger your `Test`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I edited my question as you suggested. I'm only using import selenium Webdriver and Chromedriver now and have fixed the backslash issue but I'm still getting the Select Java Application screen. However, my Java build path does contain many jars, some at least look junit related from old projects where selenium did work. I'll look up the correct number and names of jar files for a basic selenium project and hopefully that will fix it. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Firefox through control panel but never heard of Revo Uninstaller, so will try that as well.

Comment: @JuliePixie `Revo Uninstaller` confirms that once you uninstall any software the unwanted stuffs from the application  and registry entry is also deleted. It's worth to start your Test in a cleaner way.

Comment: Seems to be working at least on Chrome now, thanks. will try Firefox later this weekend!